# How would I use xpath to get the alternate ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have tried to get the each alternate ID from that box but with no avail I'm using Ruby on rails with Nokogiri

Here's the link to the page with alternate ID's (Look below the picture Alternate ID's) http://lol.gamepedia.com/Cain

```
<tr>
<th> Alternate IDs:
</th>
<td> wvwvvwvwwvwvvvwv (NA), 나진 카인, Nurinim, 나진 카인
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following XPath to get the alternate Ids value :

```
//tr/th[normalize-space()='Alternate IDs:']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Brief explanation :

- `//tr` : find all `<tr>` elements anywhere in the HTML document
- `/th[normalize-space()='Alternate IDs:']` : from the found `tr` elements, find child element `th` having inner text (after removing excess whitespaces) equals `"Alternate IDs:"`
- `following-sibling::td[1]` : from such `th`, return the first `td` element that follow the `th` element within the same parent `tr`

Comment: Do you know how you would try get each string from something like this?                                                                                                           `<td>IIlIIllIlII (NA)                                                                                              <br>SKT T1 Impact                                                                                          <br>Storm Impact                                                                                                <br>TiP Impact (NA)<br>Painsimpact (NA)<br>Yasuo Gosu (NA)
</td>`

Comment: @JasonAttwood I don't know nokogiri, but in XPath I can add `/text()` at the end to get each text/string separately